# CSS different font-size Windows/Linux/Mac

Tags: css, font-size

I'm using in CSS:

`font-family:Arial,Helvetica,"Nimbus Sans L",sans-serif;`

`font-size: 11px;`

The dimensione of the text in Windows XP/Vista/7 on Firefox/IE/Safari is different from OSx on Firefox/Safari and Ubuntu on Firefox.

Anyone know why this happens and has a solution for fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

yes I had found this exact same problem,

this is because mac actually very slightly bolds every single font, sometimes noticably sometimes not, but enough to make a different to you.

do a google search for "css hacks" and have a root around or google saearch specifically "css font hacks"

alternatively try some obvious things like setting font-weight to none, or setting line height to 1.5 em:

let me know if this helps